# MonacaでAndroidハードウェアのメニューボタンの押下を検出したい

Tags: monaca, cordova

Android はハードウェアの戻るボタンとメニューボタンが備わっています。
ホームボタンの右側にある漢字の "三" のようなメニューボタンです。
このメニューボタンがクリックされたときの挙動を制御することは可能でしょうか。
戻るボタンは下記サイトに記載がありました。

http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#HandlingBackButton

これと同じようなことをメニューボタンでも実現することは可能でしょうか？

何かご存知の方がおりましたらご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

Cordova(6.1.1 で確認)には[`menubutton`というイベント](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#menubutton)があるのでこれを捕捉します。

```js
navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);
document.addEventListener("menubutton", function(){
    alert("Hello Menu!");
}, false);
```

`navigator.app.overrideButton`が必要なのですが、現在ドキュメントには`navigator.app`についての記載はありません。バグといってよいでしょう。

---

追記:
古いCordovaだと[そもそもmenubuttonのイベントが発生しないというバグ](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9949)がありました。
古いCordovaを使い続ける場合はあきらめるか、`CordovaWebViewImpl.java`と`CoreAndroid.java`を自分で直すしかないです。
当該commit: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/b6a329d479e15cdf8a7a30a8fea9c5799c73841a

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
教えていただいたコードで確認してみましたが、現在私が開発している Cordova 5.2 では対応していないのか、alert メッセージが表示されませんでした。

Comment: @nicorobin 追記しました。自分で直す場合も数行のことですから簡単だとは思います。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。自分が開発している Monaca の環境では CordovaWebViewImpl.java と  CoreAndroid.java のファイル自体がありません。おそらく cordova-loader.js というファイルがあるのでその中で cordova 関連のファイルが読み込まれるのではないかと思うのですが、詳しくは理解できていません。とりあえず今回はメニューボタンの対応はあきらめます。回答ありがとうございました。